# Create a uniform distribution in R and it's histogram is weird

Tags: r, uniform-distribution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeCFT.png)

```
c1<- seq(1,10,0.1)
hist(c1, breaks = 7, right = FALSE, ylim = c(1,10))
```

why is there always a part that is higher at the edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there are 11 values in `c1` that are between 9.0 and 10.0 (both inclusive).
For each other bin, for example, [1, 2) there are only 10 values, as the upper edge belongs to the next bin. But for the last bin, the upper edge (10.0) is included.

If you only run your sequence until 9.9, you get the desired histogram

```
c1 <- seq(1, 9.9, 0.1)
hist(c1, breaks = 7, right = FALSE, ylim = c(1,10))
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I am quite new in R this really helps!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer answered your question, please accept it (the checkmark on the left). This way other users will know that what I wrote solves the problem and I gain a little reputation :)